# Adding new line to label

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

I get the data from the database and display that data on the label. I have to apply new line on the text of the label for every 35 charecters. Because after 35 charecters the text overflows.

Can you please let me know how to do this.

Comment: @spender - I'm assuming ASP.NET label control

Comment: yes it is asp.net label control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the style of the label so it will wrap the text:

```
style=" width:50px; overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto; word-break:break-all;"
```

Better yet, put this in your CSS file rather than directly on the control.

Another option, if you don't like this, is to use a textbox and style it as a label, as described in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200130150827/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/stealthiscode/archive/2006/03/21/WrapLabels.aspx) post.

Comment: I've got validation errors in CSS 2.0 and 2.1. Is "word-break" CSS 3.0 ?

Comment: @Slauma - Yes, it is CSS 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to do this, you would better create more labels. you could add `<br/>`, but asp.net will screen it. consider putting single label inside div with fixed width, the text should go to new line automatically.

Comment: "putting single label inside div with fixed width". Simple.

Answer (score 1):

quick psuedo code

```
string s = 'value from db';
string s2 = "";
int len = s.Length;
int i = 0;
while ( i + 35 > len ) {
  s2 += s.Substring( i, 35 ) + "\r\n";
  i+=35;
}
s2 += s.Substring( i, len - i );
label.Text = s2;
```

if  \r\n does not work, replace it with < br >

Answer (score 0):

```
//assuming l is a label
for (int i = 0; i < l.Text.Length; i++)
{
  if (i % 35 == 0)
    l.Text.Insert(i, Environment.NewLine) // or use "<br />" for html break since browsers ignore whitespace (except IE 6 in some cases)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Properties window you can change the label's Width and Height. You should set the label size based on the size of window and size of label type must pixel.

Comment: Sorry i forget to say you can find Width and Height on the properties window and Maximumsize subhead..

Comment: And what it actually does?? It changes the styles for the label. And this is done via CSS. Is it a good practice?? NO. WHY?? as it makes styles embedded in the your ascx

Answer (score -1):

```
use Environment.NewLine
```

Comment: browser will ignore it, it is html