# How to break lable text line in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and recently I made a guestbook and I don't know how to break body lable text. I used this code which cannot solve my problem:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="UserID" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;color: #284775;">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="SubjectLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="CommentDateLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("CommentDate") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="BodyLabel" runat="server"  Width="300" Text='<%# Eval("Body").ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="UserurlLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Userurl") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="CommentIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CommentId") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>



Text='<%# Eval("Body").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />" ) %>' />`
```

I searched every where in google and bing e.t.c without success, can anyone help me about solve this problem?

Comment: Does the contents of `Eval("Body")` actually have newline characters in it?  Can you post a link to your actual page, or do ["View Source"](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm) in your browser and paste the result in, say [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
<asp:Label ID="BodyLabel" **style="word-wrap: break-word"**  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Body").ToString() %> />
```

or look at this sample : [Adding new line to label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365967/adding-new-line-to-label)

Comment: Thank you very much you solved my problem appreciate so much for your help keep the good job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you just add `<br/>` string into you Label text. Because the Label is a span tab in html, like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="SubjectLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %><br/>' />
```

Comment: Actually, where do you want this new line?

Comment: I WANT TO USE IT IN <asp:Label ID="BodyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Body") %>' />

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Replace("\r\n", "<br />");` in your tag

```
Text='<%# Eval("Body").ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />") %>' />
```

combining

```
 <asp:Label ID="BodyLabel" runat="server" 
      Text='<%# Eval("Body").ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />") %>' />
```

Comment: <asp:Label ID="BodyLabel" runat="server" 
      Text='<%# Eval("Body").ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />") %>' /> but still same problem

Comment: what kind of problem?

Comment: This Lable is inside Listview i tried above methods but still have same problem

Comment: which *character* is there for new line character in your database.  Or from where you put the values in you database?

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the `Width`:

```
<asp:Label ID="BodyLabel" Width="300px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Body").ToString() %> />
```

Or - If you want exact breaks just do: `Replace("\n", "<br />");`